# ASP.NET - C# Reflection: AddObject results in "Ambiguous match found exception" during Runtime

Tags: .net, reflection

I am developing the Save Profile section of a web application (in ASP.NET/C#), however, I am getting an "Ambiguous match found" exception whenever the code tries to save a new profile through invoking each of the "AddObject", during runtime. The code is as follows partly:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Linq;
using Itok.DataAccess.Interfaces;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Itok.Entities;

namespace Itok.DataAccess.Repositories
{
    [Export(typeof(IProfileRepository))] 
    public class ProfileRepository : IProfileRepository
    {
        private Connection conn;
        public Int32 SaveProfile(Profile profile)
        {
            Int32 profileID1 = 0;
            Boolean HasAttributeId = false;
            profile.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            using(ItokDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
            {
                if (profile.ProfileID > 0)
               {
                    dc.Profiles.Attach(new Profile { ProfileID = profile.ProfileID }); 
                    dc.Profiles.ApplyCurrentValues(profile);
                    if (profile.Attributes != null)
                    {
                        foreach(ProfileAttribute item in profile.Attributes)
                        {
                            dc.ProfileAttributes.Attach(new ProfileAttribute
                                                        { ProfileAttributeID = item.ProfileAttributeID,
                                                       });
                            dc.ProfileAttributes.ApplyCurrentValues(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    profile.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                    //when working with new profile we don't expect attributes to be null, but check anyway
                    if (profile.Attributes != null)
                    {
                        foreach (ProfileAttribute item in profile.Attributes)
                        {                            
                            dc.ProfileAttributes.AddObject(new ProfileAttribute
                            {
                                ProfileAttributeID = item.ProfileAttributeID,
                                ProfileAttributeTypeID = item.ProfileAttributeTypeID,
                                ProfileID = item.ProfileID,
                                Response = item.Response,
                                CreateDate = item.CreateDate,
                                TimeStamp = item.TimeStamp
                            });
                            HasAttributeId = true;
                        }
                    }
                    dc.Profiles.AddObject(profile);
                }
                dc.SaveChanges();
                profileID1 = profile.ProfileID;
                if (HasAttributeId)
                {
                    var result = from pa in dc.ProfileAttributes.Include("ProfileAttributeType")
                                 where pa.ProfileID == profileID1
                                 select pa;
                    profile.Attributes = result.ToList();
                    foreach (ProfileAttribute item in profile.ProfileAttributes)
                    {
                        item.profileAttributeType = item.ProfileAttributeType;
                    }
                }
            }
            return profileID1;
        }
    }
}
```

The ItokModel.context.cs includes the following code:

```
namespace Itok.Entities
{
    public partial class ItokDataContext : ObjectContext
    {
        public const string ConnectionString = "name=ItokDataContext";
        public const string ContainerName = "ItokDataContext";
        #region Constructors
        public ObjectSet<ProfileAttribute> ProfileAttributes
        {
            get { return _profileAttributes  ?? (_profileAttributes = CreateObjectSet<ProfileAttribute>("ProfileAttributes")); }
        }
        private ObjectSet<ProfileAttribute> _profileAttributes;
    } 
}
```

The Profile.cs includes the following code:

```
namespace Itok.Entities
{
    public partial class Profile
    {
        public List<ProfileAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
        public LevelOfExperienceType levelOfExperienceType { get; set; }
        public Profile()
        {
            Attributes = new List<ProfileAttribute>();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the StackTrace:

```
at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr,  Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
at System.Type.GetProperty(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression expression, String propertyOrFieldName)
at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.CreateBaseGetter(Type declaringType, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
at System.Data.Objects.Internal.PocoPropertyAccessorStrategy.GetNavigationPropertyValue(RelatedEnd relatedEnd)
at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapper`1.GetNavigationPropertyValue(RelatedEnd relatedEnd)
at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupFKValuesFromNonAddedReferences()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AddSingleObject(EntitySet entitySet, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, String argumentName)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1.AddObject(TEntity entity)
at Itok.DataAccess.Repositories.ProfileRepository.SaveProfile(Profile profile) in C:\Users\S400\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Itok\Itok\DataAccess\Repositories\ProfileRepository.cs:line 84
```

Does anybody have an idea how to avoid this exception??

Comment: In fact based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103(v=vs.110).aspx   , there are a couple of situations that "Ambiguous match found" may happen. 
I have tried different ways (like Class view/Object browser settings -> show inherited members) to see if there is a hidden inheritance for properties with the same name in classes; however, obviously either the class view and/or object browser couldn't show any relationship between classes. Could anybody see anything, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared the exception successfully. Thanks all guys for good replies and comments.

But for those who still have difficulty and to save time in finding the exception, you may find below steps helpful to follow and clear the exceptions easier:

1. Don't distract yourself by too many instances through googling, those might not cope exactly your case (although many of them are directive). In fact the most trustable way is to rely on MSDN directions;
2. Situations in which AmbiguousMatchException occurs include the following:

2-1. A type contains two indexed properties that have the same name but different numbers of parameters. To resolve the ambiguity, use an overload of the GetProperty method that specifies parameter types.

2-2. A derived type declares a property that hides an inherited property with the same name, using the new modifier (Shadows in Visual Basic). To resolve the ambiguity, include BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly to restrict the search to members that are not inherited.

3. It is a bit time consuming, while quite efficient to look up "method name dropdown list" and you have a good chance of finding "same name methods or properties" up there.

Best Regards
Babak Soltan